# What is the default username and password for h2 when there's nothing explicit in JDBC?

Tags: h2

From a program, I created a H2 database without specifying any user or password in the JDBC URL.

Now I'm trying to access that database with the Script tool. The doc says to use `-user sa` in  the default case. That doesn't work, and it still doesn't work if I either add `-password sa` or remove `-user`. What am I missing?

```
/opt/h2/bin java -cp h2-1.3.161.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:/data/jug/jas-coref.h2 -user sa -password sa -script /data/jug/ris-start.sql
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-161]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:135)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:301)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:146)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:285)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at org.h2.tools.Script.execute(Script.java:152)
at org.h2.tools.Script.execute(Script.java:133)
at org.h2.tools.Script.runTool(Script.java:101)
at org.h2.tools.Script.main(Script.java:51)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Well, duh, that didn't take long.

The answer is `-user ""`.

Comment: There's an enforced delay in accepting one's own answer. If I didn't think that some other person was fairly likely to step in this particular hole, I'd have just deleted the whole business, but as it is I think that there's some chance of utility.

Comment: This was actually useful to me. Glad you kept the question and anwer.

Comment: @bmargulies Glad that you have thought "Someone might step in this hole". Because I did and wasted about 4 hours of my precious time. Also, Spark's java libraries sucks big time!

Answer (score 53):

This might work:

```
name = "sa"
password = ""
```

Comment: @Ruddy I think it does, whether or not it's a good answer is a matter for up or down votes.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For `jdbc:h2:file:~/test`, use: username="", password=""

Answer (score 6):

In case you got stuck with the default non-blank user when running the client, the full set of parameters will get you past that:

```
java -cp <path_to_h2>\h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:<jdbc_url>" -driver "org.h2.Driver" -user "" -password ""
```

Answer (score 2):

The user name is: <kbd>sa</kbd> and password not required

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your application.properties file please add

```
       spring.datasource.username=username
       spring.datasource.password=password
```

hope it helps

Comment: Question does not mention Spring.

Comment: sorry I thought it was

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you are getting this error when trying to login via Intellij, you need to enable MIXED_MODE. See this answer for more details: [Connect to H2 database using IntelliJ database client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940912/connect-to-h2-database-using-intellij-database-client)

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had mispelled the `username` and `password` properties, so i assume spring tried to use the defaults which didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I had a case in which, using H2 in memory for testing, the connection failed if I tried to connect with different credentials multiple times. This test:

```
public class H2Test {
    @Test
    public void differentCredentials() throws SQLException {
        connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "foo", "");
        connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "bar", "");
    }
    private void connect(
            String url, String username, String password
    ) throws SQLException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", username);
        props.put("password", password);
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    }
}
```

fails with error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-196]
```

This instead doesn't:

```
public class H2Test {
    @Test
    public void sameCredentials() throws SQLException {
        connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "foo", "");
        connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "foo", "");
    }
    private void connect(
            String url, String username, String password
    ) throws SQLException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", username);
        props.put("password", password);
        DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    }
}
```

That said, I couldn't find a piece of documentation that confirms this behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Script -user "sa" -password "" -url "jdbc:h2:path_to_your_db_file"
```

Comment: Please consider adding some context around your code, rather than posting a code-only answer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and redundant. See the accepted answer.