# can't login to h2 database from h2 console after using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

i found answer as user name must be left blank from url [What is the default username and password for h2 when there's nothing explicit in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695420/what-is-the-default-username-and-password-for-h2-when-theres-nothing-explicit-i) 
and i was also logged in .
But My Question is Why should i use blank username  instead of "sa" ??

Comment: I would say this depends how you have created the H2 database. When you created the database with an empty user name you should connect with an empty user name.

Comment: No SubOptimal ... yesterday also i logged in using "sa" as username .. and Now today i've created a DataSource using JDBC in Eclipse and also given Credentials as username "sa" and pwd as blank ... it is connected successfully but .. when i start the H2 Console.. its saying "wrong username or password "

Comment: You meant you create the database with `user="sa" passwd=""` and now you can connect with `user="" passwd=""`? Maybe I missunderstand what's your problem.

Comment: Yes .. SubOptimal .. can you please help me ? ?

Comment: Can't tell you what went wrong. 
If you can connect with an empty user name so what's your problem?

Comment: i'm just enquiring why that happened ? in application we are using user as "sa" but by console we are using the user as blank ..

Comment: Normally this is not possible. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done in Eclipse is instead of giving

```
"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"
```

in connection url I've given

```
"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/"
```

and gave db name as `test`. 
So I deleted `test.mv` file in windows user folder. Now Everything working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When a H2 database was created with a specific user name then it's not possible to connect to the database leaving the user name empty and vice versa.

Verified with the H2 version mentioned in your link: 1.3.161

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestH2 {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./test", "sa", "")) {
            System.out.println(conn);
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(255))";
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTable);
            String insertStmnt = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(1, 'CAFEBABE');";
            int count = conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(insertStmnt);
            System.out.printf("inserted rows: %d%n", count);
        }

        // will fail with org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-181]
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./test", "", "")) {
            System.out.println(conn);
            String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM TEST_TABLE";
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("id: %d  name: %s%n", rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("NAME"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```